# Moving a WordPress site from one folder to another (one domain, one server)

Tags: migration

There's actually a lot of similar question and answers but most of them related to transfer from one server to another and from one domain to another.

The thing I want to do is to create a folder "new_version" within existing web-site, setup WordPress to "new_version", fill in the content, make sure that everything is OK and then - delete old version and copy "new_version" to the root folder.

As DB will not be changed and the domain will be the same (just the folder will be changed) - am I able to do something easy to accomplish this?

May be just copy of `new_version` folder contents to root web directory? Anything else will be needed?

Comment: Follow the same procedure as domain change. It should work that way..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the step-by-step instructions to move your WordPress site to a new location on the same server:

1. Create the new location using one of these two options:

   1. If you will be moving your WordPress core files to a new directory, create the new directory. (in my case , i made a folder named 'kombat' in www directory of wamp server)
   2. If you want to move WordPress to your root directory, make sure all index.php, .htaccess, and other files that might be copied over are backed up and/or moved, and that the root directory is ready for the new WordPress files.
2. Log in to your site.
3. Go to the Administration > Settings > General panel.
4. In the box for WordPress Address (URL): change the address to the new location of your main WordPress core files. (e.g. http://localhost/kombat)
5. In the box for Site Address (URL): change the address to the new location, which should match the WordPress (your public site) address. (e.g. localhost/kombat)
6. Click Save Changes.
7. (Do not try to open/view your site now!)
8. Move your WordPress core files to the new location. This includes the files found within the original directory, and all the sub-directories, to the new location.
9. Now, try to open your site by going to yourdomain.com/wp-admin. Note, you may need to go to yourdomain.com/wp-login.php (e.g. i visited localhost/kombat )

These steps were enough for me. you can read the full procedure at http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Comment: As you mentioned *7.(Do not try to open/view your site now!)* I assume that this will not work for 'living' site as any user can try to access the site at any time? So I need to apply a 'under service' temporary page for this purpose?

Comment: @RomanMatveev actually i don't know why this step is important . Don't know what should be best for a live website. sorry